# Error with changing legends in histogram and density plot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, legend, density-plot

I have the next dataset:

```
 structure(list(working_hours = c("Whours_after", "Whours_after", 
"Whours_before", "Whours_before", "Whours_before", "Whours_before", 
"Whours_after", "Whours_after", "Whours_after", "Whours_after", 
"Whours_after", "Whours_before", "Whours_before", "Whours_after", 
"Whours_after", "Whours_before", "Whours_after", "Whours_after", 
"Whours_before", "Whours_after", "Whours_after", "Whours_before", 
"Whours_before", "Whours_after", "Whours_before", "Whours_before", 
"Whours_after", "Whours_after", "Whours_before", "Whours_after"
), value = c(12.6000003814697, 21, NA, NA, 42, 42, 42, 21, 42, 
42, 0, 0, 42, 42, 0, 42, 42, 36.9599990844727, 16.7999992370605, 
8.39999961853027, 42, 42, 42, 0, 29.3999996185303, 10.5, 42, 
42, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

I have created the next plot histogram and two densities. But I dont know how to change the numbers in the legend:

```
p<-ggplot(datas,aes(x=value,fill=working_hours,color=working_hours))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),alpha=0.5,binwidth = 3,position="identity")+
  geom_density(alpha=.3)+labs(title="Histrogram")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c( "#ED0000FF","#4668BDFF"))
```

[image]

I have found information on internet that I need to include

```
p+scale_fill_manual(values=c( "#ED0000FF","#4668BDFF"))+scale_fill_discrete(name = "Dose", labels = c("A", "B"))
```

However when I include this I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that by adding `scale_fill_discrete` you are overwriting the `scale_fill_manual`. Second, you are mapping on both the `color` and `fill` aesthetic. However, by specifying a `name` and `labels` only for the `fill` scale the legends for `color` and `fill` will no longer get merged and you end up with two different legends, one for `color` and one for `fill`.

To fix your first issue drop the `scale_fill_discrete` and assign your labels via the `name` and `labels` argument of `scale_fill_manual`.

To fix your second issue you have to add a corresponding `scale_color_manual` with the same color palette, name and labels or by applying the `fill` scale to both the `color` and `fill` aesthetic by adding `aesthetics = c("fill", "color")` to `scale_fill_manual`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(datas, aes(x = value, fill = working_hours, color = working_hours)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(density)),
    alpha = 0.5, binwidth = 3, position = "identity"
  ) +
  geom_density(alpha = .3) +
  labs(title = "Histrogram") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#ED0000FF", "#4668BDFF"),
    aesthetics = c("fill", "color"),
    name = "Dose", labels = c("A", "B")
  )
```

[image]